# Enable button if form value matches value

Tags: html, angular, validation

when value from  formarray control amount eqauls  value from ,  i need to enable submit  button.
My code as follows:

```
                                 <button *ngIf="i===0" pButton type="button"
                                            class="button-add" icon="pi pi-plus" pTooltip="Add"
                                            (click)="addNewRow()"
                                            tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>

                                    <button *ngIf="i!== 0" pButton type="button"
                                            (click)="deleteRow(i)"
                                            class="button-add" icon="pi pi-minus" pTooltip="Delete"
                                            tooltipPosition="bottom"></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

  <button  pButton type="button" label="Submit"
                            (click)="onSubmit()"
                            class="button-add"></button>&nbsp;
```

ts code

```
 addNewRow() {
        this.formArr.push(this.());
    }

    deleteRow(index: number) {
        this.formArr.removeAt(index);
    }
```

Comment: When you say `amount` equals value from json, what do you mean? Where is json coming from?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 - building function to check**

Add disabled to your button calling a function

```
<button  pButton type="button" label="Submit"
                            [disabled]="!amountValid()"
                            (click)="onSubmit()"
                            class="button-add"></button>&nbsp;
```

Create the function as follows

```
amountValid(): boolean {
    const paymentArray = this.paymentForm.get('paymentDetails') as FormArray;
    let totalValue = 0;

    paymentArray.controls.forEach((group: FormGroup) => {
      totalValue += +group.get('amount').value
    });

    if (totalValue == this.jsonValue) {
      console.log('true');
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

**Method 2 - Using a validatorFn (Recommended)**

Build your form with a validator on the formArray

```
this.paymentForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        paymentDetails: this.fb.array([this.buildPaymentDetailsForm()], {validators: this.amountValidation()})
      }
    );
```

Create a validatorFn that checks the array

```
amountValidation(): ValidatorFn {
    return (details: FormArray): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      let totalValue = 0;
      details.controls.forEach((group: FormGroup) => {
        totalValue += +group.get('amount').value;
      });

      if (totalValue == this.jsonValue) {
        console.log('true');
        return null;
      }

      return { invalidAmount: true };
    };
  }
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formarray-validatorfn-akejdu